# Spacing in a list, cannot seem to override the <h3> automatic space

Tags: html, css

Ok, I am probably missing the simple solution once again, but frustration is quickly setting in.  What I want to do is be able to set the space between the list items.  My problem is I cannot seem to override the space created by the h3 tag.

```
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><h3>The Oscar is only worth $1</h3></li>
        <li><h3>It takes 10 days to make one Oscar</h3></li>
        <li><h3>The statuettes are 24K gold plated, bronze underneath</h3></li>
        <li><h3>For 3 years during WWII, the statues were made of plaster</h3></li>
        <li><h3>Over 3000 Oscars have been awarded</h3></li>
        <li><h3>The statues are 8.5 pounds and 13.5 inches tall</h3></li>
    </ul>
```

I've tried creating a class with the h3 tag but no luck.  I've tried different lines in css such as:

```
    li{
      margin: 10px 0;
    }
```

or

```
    li { padding: 10px 0px 0px; }
    li:first-child { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

or

```
    li:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

I can't change the h3 tag spacing in css because the tag is used on other pages. Could something be done so the h3 tag is not needed on each li line? Maybe something via javascript as a last resort? 
**HELP!!**

Comment: `because the tag is used on other pages.` ---> use class, apply to only this page, use specific selector, etc, etc,etc

Comment: @Keshav I don't mean to complain, but your editing totally changed my question about the spacings and what I tried to make things work.  Totally messed up now.  If someone has the ability, or would tell me how to do it, the way it is now, the whole question would be better off deleted.

Comment: I am very sorry. Can you please edit the question and make it correct.

Comment: I appreciate the apology.  I have no problem with my questions being edited for content or better formatting than I originally had, but the meaning/scope behind the question shouldn't be changed.  Just my opinion though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you can target the `h3` tag specifically.  The issue is you're trying to fix styling for h3 on the containing li.  That isn't how CSS works.  You have to target the problematic element directly to override the CSS.

```css
li h3 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><h3>The Oscar is only worth $1</h3></li>
    <li><h3>It takes 10 days to make one Oscar</h3></li>
    <li><h3>The statuettes are 24K gold plated, bronze underneath</h3></li>
    <li><h3>For 3 years during WWII, the statues were made of plaster</h3></li>
    <li><h3>Over 3000 Oscars have been awarded</h3></li>
    <li><h3>The statues are 8.5 pounds and 13.5 inches tall</h3></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but out of curiousity, why wouldn't the spacing work by creating a class that had the margin set, something like h3 class="space" then have the class set in css as margin: 10px or along those lines?

Comment: @BradAnderson That would work as long as the class is on the h3 tag, so `<h3 class="space">test</h3>`.  Then css would be `.space {margin:10px 0;}`

Comment: I swear I tried that, but it works now and that is what counts!  Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score -1):

```
li h3 {
  margin: 0px 0;
}
```

This CSS can change h3 space.

Comment: OP says "I've tried creating a class with the h3 tag but no luck.". So it seems it's not related to the margin of the h3.